# Виртуальный список со скролом на всю страницу

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

у кого есть экспертиза в Виртуальных списках?

Использую https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller
Он требует , чтобы обертка его была с фикс высотой (чтобы у него свой оверфлоу был), иначе работает с глюками (не удаляет елементы из дома).

Так вот:

- Eсть бесконечный список среди прочих елементов на странице.
  Сложность в том, что скролл нужно отображать НЕ в рамках этого виртуального списка, а в рамках страницы .
  [image: как выглядит сейчас]

НУЖНО: как в инсте - см пример на фото №2

[image: пример как должно быть]

Как вытащить скролл из под этого вирт. списка?

- передавать евент скролла со страницы в контейнер с листом?
- как скролл рисовать? вирутально? - костыль .

Comment: Смотрите "page mode" в плагине. Ну или Вы можете попробовать задать 100vw 100vh для контейнера и поместить его назад (`z-index: 0`), остальные элементы вперед (скорее всего они у Вас уже и так `position: fixed`). А сами карточки не на всю ширину тогда, + позиционировать надо.